# Disable desktop menu mode bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, menubar

Bootstrap menu, as I know, has 2 modes: "desktop" mode "phone/tablet" mode. The desktop mode is anything above 767px width, and the later is anything bellow or equal (to 767px). I do not need desktop mode, how do i achieve phone/tablet mode across all resolutions?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4kffc3ccnhb0dc/design.png

Answer (score 2):

If you want do this with CSS (as opposed to LESS) you need to override a whole bunch of classes related to the collapsing navbar. **You'll get this result: http://www.bootply.com/Yw4atsJ6U0**

```
@media (max-width: 3000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 0px 0px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Other than these overrides, edit the stock responsive menu HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse always-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick to `col-xs-*`or  `col-md-*` (1 through 12) and you're good to go. If you're not clear what that means, see the bootstrap documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Comment: Thanks @shawn i'm trying to achieve the result as in the link below.https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4kffc3ccnhb0dc/design.png

Comment: right, just re-read your question and I see I missed your point entirely... another answer coming.